# How can I display a Perl/Tk window in the bottom righthand corner?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have planned to do the chatting the exercise Perl socket. In this I want to display 
the require window using Perl/Tk. Here my requirement is that the window has to display in the bottom right corner. It is like Gmail Chat window. What do I need to achieve this? 
By default it displays in top left corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
# Main Window
my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->geometry('+793+475');  # Slightly down to the right
MainLoop;
```

Comment: better still would be `geometry('-x-y')` which allows window placement relative to the bottom right corner of the screen and window so you don't have to guess at the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

[Tk::Wm->geometry](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/lib/Tk/Wm.html#geometry_management)